# Is it possible to use the context of a state in another state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a project in ReactJS. I have a context folder that contain different context folders. It looks like this.

[image: context folder]

Each of the folder has ...Context.js, ...Reducer.js, and ...State.js files. In my AuthStaste.js, I have a clearError() function as shown here:

[image: AuthState.js clearError()]

In my ContactState.js, I have error object property declared in the initialState. Since I already have clearError defined in AuthState.js, I want to know if there is a way I can make use of the function in my ContactState.js without redefining it.

Comment: Just export and reuse it.

Comment: Even though I import it to my ContactState.js, I still have to dispatch in the ContactReducer.js, don't I?

Comment: I can't know. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)